# Next.js - Using 3rd-party package imports everything in all bundle

Tags: next.js, code-splitting, tree-shaking

Currently, we are using a custom 3rd-party package "custom/package".

Although it doesn't do tree shake and doesn't separate the package into a different bundle.

Is there a possible way for webpack or something to just make that package into a separate common bundle?